# Do votes on comments count as votes (or do only votes on questions & answers qualify)?

Tags: support, comment, voting, badges

Regarding badges (and anything else that votes might count toward): do votes on comments *count* as "votes", or do only votes on questions and/or answers qualify as such?

*Please note that this is not about reputation (which is a question that has been asked by someone else, as well as answered).*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Votes on comments are treated separately from votes on posts.
In particular:

- The typical voting badges like  Civic Duty, Electorate, Suffrage, Vox Populi concern votes on posts *only*.
- The daily limit for votes on comments and votes on posts are treated separately, both are 30, at least basically  (I'll not enter details of rate limits here). That is, you can upvote 30 comments and in addition 30 posts.

See [The Complete Rate-Limiting Guide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164899/the-complete-rate-limiting-guide) for the rate limits.

Comment: Coincidentally, I kind of reached 39/40 Q&A votes yesterday in the non-meta chess exchange (at some point after having posted the above question about comment-votes). Having immediately thereafter researched the 30+10 limitation somewhat exhaustively, I <i>very</i> much understand leaving off the rate details herein. Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 6):

[I believe that](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/51607/194594) the only badge that has to do with the votes on comments is the pundit badge.

Comment: I would not have thought of the pundit page. And this while I comment so much. :-)